# How can I include XCTest as a dependency in a Swift (SPM) package?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, swift-package-manager

I am making a Swift package to extend the functionality of XCTest, but am having trouble building my app's tests when the package is used.

---

I've begun by importing XCTest to one of my package's (non-test) class files. In that file, I'll use that class to work with XCTest (for example, `XCUIScreen`). The entire package compiles without error.

I have added my test helper package as a local dependency to another app I'm building on my machine. Then I set up the package in the app's test target, under the "Link Binary With Libraries" section.

I can import my test helper package to my app's test class, but when I try to use the package's class, I get the following build error:

```
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'XCTestSwiftSupport': library 'XCTestSwiftSupport' not found
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'XCTest': framework 'XCTest' not found
ld: Undefined symbols:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_XCUIScreen, referenced from:
       in MyXcodeTestHelper.o
  __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_XCTestSwiftSupport, referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_XCTestSwiftSupport_$_MyXcodeTestHelper in MyXcodeTestHelper.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

---

Is there a configuration I've missed, or something I can add to my package description file to indicate XCTest should be a dependency? If it's not possible, are there any good alternatives? I am using Xcode 15.0.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you change the ENABLE_TESTING_SEARCH_PATHS to YES?